# C# Remove element from List in DataGridView with button works only once

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview

I've got delete button at the end of each row (second column) of DataGridView. On click I remove row from DataGrid and from the list which is data source of my grid.

[image]

```
private List<multiSet> createdMap = new List<multiSet>();
```

On button click I can delete element form my DataGridView (named `DrawGrid` ), but it works only for first click, then I can't delete any element

```
private void DrawGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0)
            return;

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
                createdMap.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
                DrawGrid.DataSource = createdMap.ToList();
        }

    }
```

Comment: When debugging, does it enter the DrawGrid_CellContentClick or does just nothing happen when you click the button?

Comment: What's the code that creates the rows?

Comment: yes, after ferst delete on debugging it enter DrawGrid_CellContentClick, but nothing more happens - it clames that column index is 0 (although buttons column =1)

Comment: when you first set the DataSource of DrawGrid try doing it like this... `DrawGrid.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = createdMap.ToList() };` and remove `DrawGrid.DataSource = createdMap.ToList()` in DrawGrid_CellContentClick.

Comment: @dgc
DataGridView store elements from createdMap, which is generated before with some random numbers
 `DrawGrid.DataSource = createdMap;`

Comment: this still works only for first click  @BlakeThingstad but thanks your question I found the answer :D

Comment: Instead of `List<T>`  use `BindingList<T>` for data binding.

Comment: @RezaAghaei in this unfortunetly I can't change this data structure, but i will not work in this case

Comment: Then to refresh grid,  just set `DrawGrid.DstaSource = null` and then `DrawGrid.DataSource = createdMap;`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei it works! thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using only 2 columns and form my DataGridView Design MetroUI framework, so I don't need to check if my column index is 1, because it is impossible to click column 0, which is used to edit numbers.

So it's enough to delete my elements just right that:

```
private void DrawGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0)
            return;

        createdMap.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        DrawGrid.DataSource = createdMap.ToList();
    }
```

According to @RezaAghaei answer this is better idea:

```
private void MultisetGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex < 0)
                return;

            if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                createdMap.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
                DrawGrid.DataSource = null;
                DrawGrid.DataSource = createdMap;
            }

        }
```

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me, but if it works then okay =P

Comment: Yes, I agree it looks quite strange, but MetroUI (for winforms) is not well documented framework, and probably it shouldn't work like that :D